# Javascript counter on php page

Tags: php, javascript

I've got a java script counter on my php page.  (I should probably add that I don't know java script).  It display's the time the user is active on the page.  My problem is if the user presses F5 or refreshes the page the counter starts from 0 again.  How do I change this so that it remembers the time?  Help will be greatly appreciated.

**Javascript:**

```
var pageVisisted = new Date(); 

setInterval(function() {
    var timeOnSite = new Date() - pageVisisted;

    var secondsTotal = timeOnSite / 1000;
    var hours = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 60) % 3600;
    var seconds = Math.floor(secondsTotal)  % 60;

    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}, 1000);
```

**The php page**

```
<head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="counter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<span id='counter'></span>";
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie to do this. Since you say you don't know javascript, you might want to just review this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html where it tells you how to read and write cookies. Every time you evaluate the time on the site, just read/write to that cookie and it will still be there when the page reloads.

Comment: ok thank you, will go through it.  Just a question, what if the client computer does not have cookies enabled?  Sorry I've always stayed away from cookies because of this.

Comment: Well, if they don't have cookies they are probably used to websites not working. But your alternative would be to make Ajax callbacks to your PHP page and keep updating their session. I do not recommend that. Its about as likely that they don't have javascript as don't have cookies.

Comment: It won't work, but neither will probably 99% of all websites which use cookies to facilitate sessions. It is just as probable that the client won't allow javascript as it is that it would not store cookies, and in this case. If they are allowing javascript they most likely will also allow session cookies, and you would use a session cookie for this.  A session cookie is one that only lasts as long as the browser is open.

Comment: Actually, does PHP session work without cookies enabled? I don't know. ASP.NET has cookieless session support, so I was assuming, but don't know PHP well.

Comment: Ok thanks all, I'll begin with the cookies.  Will post back what I've done.